# Vue-MultiSelect: Using two multiselects at once and how to hide options based on what is shown in other

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3, vue-multiselect

I am using a plugin called [Vue-MultiSelect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started) and showing it twice in my component. The first multiselect  has a label of "Add New Contacts" and the second multiselect has a label of "Current Listed Contacts".

How can I hide the users for the "Add New Contacts" multiselect dropdown if they are already listed in the "Current Listed Contacts"?

Screenshot of problem:

[image]

I am using props to show the users for the "Current Listed contacts" multiselect. Here's the code for my Single file component where these multiselects reside (also demo link: [CodeSandBox Code Editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-with-pocs-works3-sot8z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FEditPost.vue&theme=dark)) *Note: click on POSTS --> EDIT (Acme Widget) to see the page where I am talking about*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Add New Contacts:</label>
    <multiselect
      id="add_new_contacts_input"
      v-model="NewContacts"
      :options="options"
      label="lastname"
      placeholder="Select or search for an existing contact"
      track-by="uid"
      :loading="isLoading"
      :custom-label="selectedNameLabel"
      aria-describedby="searchHelpBlock"
      selectLabel
      :multiple="true"
    >
      <template
        slot="singleLabel"
        slot-scope="props"
      >{{ props.option.lastname }}, {{props.option.firstname}}</template>
      <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
        <strong>{{ props.option.lastname }}</strong>
        , {{ props.option.firstname }} &mdash;
        <small>{{ props.option.email }}</small>
      </template>
    </multiselect>
    <!-- <small id="searchHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted"><font-awesome-icon icon="exclamation-circle" /> If customer does not exist, you will be prompted to add a new customer</small> -->
    <!-- <h3>New contacts to be added:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="value in values" :key="value.uid">{{value.lastname}}, {{value.firstname}}</li>
    </ul>-->
    <label>Current Listed Contacts</label>
    <multiselect
      id="current_listed_contacts_input"
      v-model="CurrentListedValues"
      placeholder="There are no current contacts"
      label="lastname"
      track-by="uid"
      :options="options"
      :multiple="true"
      :custom-label="selectedNameLabel"
      :loading="isLoading"
      selectLabel
    >
      <!-- formatting for the drop down list -->
      <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
        <strong>{{ props.option.lastname }}</strong>
        , {{ props.option.firstname }} &mdash;
        <small>{{ props.option.email }}</small>
      </template>
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
// import ApiService from "@/apiService";
export default {
  components: { Multiselect },
  props: ["users", "contacts"],
  data() {
    return {
      NewContacts: [],
      CurrentListedValues: this.contacts,
      options: this.users,
      isLoading: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.isLoading = false;
  },
  methods: {
    selectedNameLabel(option) {
      return `${option.lastname}, ${option.firstname} -- ${option.email}`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use computed to filter your list:

```
  computed: {
    addOptions() {
      let opt = this.users;
      this.CurrentListedValues.forEach(c => {
        opt = opt.filter(i => i.uid !== c.uid);
      });
      return opt;
    }
  }
```

and in your select list change options to addOptions: `:options="addOptions"`